# access response object from script block in sails

Tags: javascript, sails.js, ejs

I have a sails app. In a controller, the response object for a page looks like this:

```
response.view(template, {
    data: result,
    actionType: "edit"
  });
```

On the page I include a local script like so

```
<% block('localScripts', '<script src="/js/myscript.js"></script>') %>
```

In this script I would like to have something like

```
if(actionType === "edit") {
   //send to edit endpoint
} else {
  //send to create endpoint
}
```

But I can't access the actionType variable. Is there a way to make this variable accessible in the script, except of storing it in a hidden field?
Can I pass the variable to the script or can I access the response object from the script?

Any hint appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so strange way. Why don't you change template according to action type in controller instead of analyse somthing in template?

I suggest simple solution for your variant.
In template before insert script block do:

```
<script type="application/javasript">var actionType = <%- actionType  %></script>
```